# Достать подстроки регулярным выражением

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Мне необходимо достать из текста все подстроки, ограниченные определенными символами. Если подробнее:

> В тексте (**несколько**) раз встречаются (**слова**) в скобках. И мне (**надо**) все такие изъять.

---

Из текста выше, как вы могли догадаться, надо достать "несколько", "слова" и "надо". Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста. Вот регулярка для поиска символов между скобками: `\(.+?\)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для исключения скобок `\((.+?)\)`, останется забрать из первой группы результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подскажите ещё, скобки можно исключить самой регуляркой?

Comment: Конечно, нужно внутри скобок создать еще одни, но без экранирования: `\((.+?)\)`. Или при обработке результата регулярки, сами убирайте скобки, хоть обрезая первый и последний символ, хоть удаляя сами символы '(' и ')'

Answer (score 3):

Ну раз C#, то предлагаю вот это https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FUxrZ
Если, конечно, необходимо иметь возможность каждое слово как-либо обработать

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("В тексте (несколько) раз встречаются (слова) в скобках. И мне (надо) все такие изъять.", @"(\((?<Words>.+?)\))");

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Group g = match.Groups["Words"]; 

            Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
несколько
слова
надо
```